# Proving a conditional algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $x,y \in (0,1)$, and suppose that
$$
x^2-2x+y^2<0.
$$

How to prove that
$$
-x^3-xy^2+4y^2 \ge 0.
$$
holds?

The motivation comes from a certain geometric problem (a bit long to describe here).

Comment: Is it typo error or really the first equation's 2 nd doesn't contain $2xy$ and only contain $-2x$

Comment: if the second term contains a $2xy$, then the quadratic is a perfect square, meaning positive.

Comment: The statements don't concur either for a simple point $(1,0)$. It satisfies the first, not the second.  Draw both inequalities in DESMOS and you can see that any combination where $x$ is chosen between $1$ and $2$ in combination with $y$ chosen between $0$ and $1/2$, don't work (Satisfy the first, not the second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true because $(x,y) = (0.1, 0.01)$ satisfies the first inequality but not the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo; it was suppose to be $\ge 0$ not $\ge 1$.

Comment: @AsafShachar the statement is still not true, see my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you, I apologise for deleting my question. I just thought it wasn't useful, since it contained a silly mistake. But I understand it wasn't the right thing to do, since you already gave an answer.

Comment: @AsafShachar thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. I will say two things though: 1. It is more polite to comment if you have a personal problem with someone, rather than posting a criticizing answer at a different place. 2. If you spot something that looks like an immediate counter-example to a claim, it might be more useful to mention this in a comment, rather than immediately publishing an answer. This allows the asker of the question  the possibility to edit their question, thus making it more interesting. Again all these comments are not to justify my deletion of the question after you gave an answer, which was wrong.

Comment: @AsafShachar I fully agree but need 50 reputation to comment.